# Why is favicon shape 16x16x4 and what is wrong with the whatsapp favicon?

Tags: python-imaging-library, favicon

I am new to working with favicons, and am having trouble understanding formatting. For 2 examples:
 I pull the favicon from google.com and noticed that the shape is 16x16x4. Why not 16x16x3?

For whatsapp.com, it is 194x194, and when I try to display the image, it looks corrupted, and different when compared to jupyter notebook's build in tool for displaying images

```py
from PIL import Image
import requests
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import Image as show_Image 


def get_favicon_save_load_display(host):
    example = requests.get( "https://" +  host + '/favicon.ico')
    with open(host + ".favicon.ico", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(example.content)
    im = Image.open(host + ".favicon.ico")
    np_im = np.array(im)
    print("The image shape is: ", np_im.shape)
    plt.imshow(np_im) 
    plt.show()

get_favicon_save_load_display('google.com')
get_favicon_save_load_display('whatsapp.com')

example = requests.get('https://whatsapp.com/favicon.ico')
show_Image(example.content)
```

I would expect the image shape to be 16x16x3, and I would expect the image to be rendered the same way. Is there something obvious I am missing?

Comment: Alpha channel, probably. What does “looks corrupted” mean?

Comment: Here is a link: https://ibb.co/b3Ng1ZR you can also run this in jupyter yourself and you should get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fourth channel would be alpha, which contain transparancy information. If you read your images like this,

```
im = Image.open(host + ".favicon.ico").convert('RGBA')
```

it should be displayed properly.